# [Tooltipster Plugin]- Know if div already have tooltipster

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltipster

I'm using this plugin http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/.

**It is possible know if a HTML already have the tooltipster initialized?**

I wanna know because sometimes i need to change the text of the tooltip, and for do that, i need to destroy the tooltipster, change the attribute title of the HTML object, and initialize again. Like this:

```
$(this).tooltipster('destroy').attr("title", data.fields[i].value).tooltipster();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the API:

Check if the element already has tooltipster:

```
$(...).hasClass("tooltipstered");

$(...).tooltipster('content', myNewContent);
```

Comment: What if it has then been disabled ? It still has class ?

Comment: @Stephane Should be... This answer is about a plugin, and it has been development since then, and it's been 2 years. This might not be valid.

Answer (score 6):

Accepted solution does not work on SVG elements with tooltipster v4.1.6.
This is how I solved it:

```
if ($.tooltipster.instances($(node)).length == 0) {
    //it is NOT tooltipstered
}
else {
    //it is tooltipstered
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .hasClass to check if it has the tooltipstered class

```
var divToCheck = null; //FIXME: update to whatever query you use to get the div you're checking
if (divToCheck.hasClass('tooltipstered')) {
  //TODO: update your title
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that it needs to be instantiated or simply enabled:

```
if (!$(id).hasClass("tooltipstered")) {
    $(id).tooltipster({
     position: 'top-left',
     contentAsHTML: 'true',
     theme: '.tooltipster-default',
     animation: 'grow'
    });
} else {
    $(id).tooltipster('enable');
}
```

Make sure that you checked it is instantiated before disabling it:

```
if ($(id).hasClass("tooltipstered")) {
   $(id).tooltipster('disable');
}
```